# Is it possible to use Facebook Credits as Rewards?

Tags: facebook-credits, credits, reward

I would like to use Facebook Credits as Rewards, e.g. if a user reaches a next level or a high-score he can earn Facebook Credits. I'am planning to buy on my own (for the app) FB credits and then handing them out as rewards. In the API documentation are only functions to let the user buy App-Stuff via Facebook Credits. I couldn't find a clear answer for this question in the forum.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You will need to contact Facebook in order to do this.  They don't just let everyone do it easily and want to ensure you are authentic in your goals.  Not sure of the cost, but I am sure it is something they can provide to you.

Answer (score 0):

I tend to allow users to buy my in-game currency with Facebook Credits.  Then I can reward them with my own virtual currency and as much as I want.